# Cordova: What is the best way to send data from Plugin back to the main CordovaView?

Tags: plugins, cordova

I need to send data/objects back from a Cordova Plugin to the main Cordova View. This is to change the ActionBar title for example etc.

What would be the way to go?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Returning a [PluginResult](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android) is the accepted method. The success callback of your method will be invoked with the data you send back via the PluginResult.

Comment: The PluginResult callback leads back to the HTML layer. This works well. But i need also to talk back from the Plugin to the Activity which implements the CordovaInterface before passing control back to the HTML layer.

Comment: Then you need to create a public method in your Activity which you can call from onActivityResult. Then in your activity you can call this.sendJavascript(statement) to call code in your HTML. Over in the Plugin you would just return a dummy PluginResult.

Answer (score 1):

I have written working code to send data from  Cordova to CordovaPlugin and vice versa.

***Code For Android***

```
public class CustomPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
  @Override
  public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext             callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    Log.d(TAG, action); //doPluginAction is printed
    Log.d(TAG, args.getString(0));//parameter is printed

    PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "here you can also send you message to app from plugin"); // You can send data, String, int, array, dictionary and etc
    result.setKeepCallback(false);
    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);

    return true;
  }
}
```

***Code For iOS***

```
//CustomPlugin.h file
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CustomPlugin : CDVPlugin
-(void) doPluginAction:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*) command;
@end

//CustomPlugin.m file
#import "CustomPlugin.h"
@implementation CustomPlugin
-(void) doPluginAction:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*) command {
    CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:"here you can also send you message to app from plugin"];// You can send data, String, int, array, dictionary and etc
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];
}
@end
```

***Code for plugin js file***

```
www/CustomPlugin.js
var exec = require('cordova/exec');
exports.callPluginMethod = function (parameter, success, error) {
    exec(success, error, “CustomPlugin”, "doPluginAction", [parameter]);
};
```

***Call plugin and completion block handling:***

```
cordova.plugins.CustomPlugin.callPluginMethod("parameter", (success: any) => {
    console.log(success);
},
(error:any) => {
    console.log(error);
})
```